# Using REST WebService with Twilio CLIENT browser to phone sample code

Tags: rest, web-services, twilio

This issue is related to the use of **Twilio CLIENT** to make a direct call from browser to phone number.

I want to ask you if it is possible to replace the **request.php** with a **Rest WebService** that returns the same **TwiML** as the **request.php**.

```
@POST
@Path("directCall")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public String doDirectCall(@Context HttpServletRequest request) {                       
    String tlfCuenta = (String)request.getParameter("Caller_Id");;      
    String tlfCliente = (String)request.getParameter("To");
    
    String twiml =
            "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>"
          + "<Response>"
          + "   <Dial callerId='" + tlfCuenta + "' record='true'>" 
          + "      <Number>"
          +           tlfCliente
          + "      </Number>"
          + "   </Dial>"
          + "</Response>";
            
    return twiml;
}
```

And point to it in the field **REQUEST URL** of the **Twilio Console**.

As I see in the Twilio debugger, Twilio reach our WebService doDirectCall method, but it fails with a '**HTTP status code 415**'.

An attempt to retrieve content from https://xxx.yyy.es/avdisws/twilioCallService/directCall returned the HTTP status code 415

It seems to be a issue with the type content or something like that.

The test fails with some of the next annotation tries:

```
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})

@Produces({MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})

@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With this annotations it works:

```
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED})
@Produces({MediaType.TEXT_XML})
```